# How to insert a value into a text field under a div using Watir

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I used `set`  to insert a value in a text field under a div.

Below is the approach that I've used without success. This is the only way I was able to identify the element. When I tried to identify text field by name was not recognized.

```
@browser.div(:evaluation, :id => "evaluation_form_attributes").text_field(:id => "evaluation_form_name")
@browser.set('Teacher Evaluation Form')
```

The following error was displayed:

```
undefined method `set' for #<Watir::IE:0x4dd9348>
```

This is the HTML:

```
div id="evaluation_form_attributes"
```

Evaluation name:

```
input id="evaluation_form_name" type="text" size="50" name="evaluation_form[name]" maxlength="30"
```

Comment: Were you finally able to find the text_field?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
browser.text_field(:id => "evaluation_form_name").set 'Teacher Evaluation Form'
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! I have tried this method before but I m getting this error when i try to access the element           Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: Unable to locate element, using {:id=>"evaluation_form_name"}

Comment: be sure the ID is spelled right, and also search the page code to be sure it is unique and not used elsewhere on the page.   Per HTML standards ID's are supposed to be unique within a page.  functions that try to identify via ID values will tend to fail of the page violates HTML standards and the ID values are not unique

Answer (score 1):

Is there an iframe involved perhaps?  if you know the thing is there, and you are sure of the ID, and watir cannot locate it, then usually it's because that part of the page is inside of a frame.

To work with elements that are inside of a frame, you must specify the frame, then the element

browser.frame(:how, what).element(:how, what).method   etc.

see http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Frames for more info

Comment: So how can you navigate inside the iframe?

Comment: see the link I added to the answer when I edited it just now.  or google using terms like: watir wiki frames

Answer (score 0):

To set a value for a text field you simply need to find it and set it. The setting part you already know (`set`), so you need to string together something that finds the text field.

if Zejiko's answer doesn't work because of "unable to locate element" then it's not the setting that's failing, it's finding the text field. Use Firebug (in Firefox) or some kind of DOM toolkit (Tools>Developer Tools or F12 in IE8) to find the text field and see what kind of attributes it has.

Ensure the id is really `"evaluation_form_name"`. This is case sensitive and sensitive to leading/trailing spaces. You could try the following to make your search broader:

```
@browser.text_field(:id => /evaluation/).set 'Teacher Evaluation Form'
```

This uses a regular expression to identify the id. You can search by many things, not just :id, and you can use more than one. For example:

```
@browser.text_field(:id => /eval/, :index => 2)
```

finds the second text field whose id contains "eval".

What you can use to identify the text field can be found here: https://github.com/watir/watir/wiki/HTML-Elements-Supported-by-Watir

Comment: Thank you for the answers .. still have't been able to identify the text field by id or name. What is weird is that I use the same method to identify text fields on other pages and it works fine.. just with this one I have problems

Comment: You could try identifying it by index alone, to see if it can be found, or by some other attribute. If it's in a form this used to cause problems, unknown whether it still does. You could identify the container (the div) first, then use index within the div (e.g. 3rd text field in the div is .div(:id=>'imadiv').text_field(:index=>3) ). If none of these work you'll need to post a link or some HTML so we can see how it looks, or failing that you could try xpath! Also make sure it's not a timing issue (trying to find the text field before it exists)